# Android NumberPicker negative numbers show different values

Tags: java, android, numberpicker

I use NumberPicker with negative numbers by:

```
int maxValue = 50;
int minValue = -20;

NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
np.setDisplayedValues(null);
np.setMinValue(0);
np.setMaxValue(maxValue - minValue);
np.setValue(Math.abs(minValue)); // start from 0
np.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
np.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);

String[] values = new String[maxValue - minValue];
int key = 0;

for (int i = minValue; i < maxValue; i++) {
    values[key] = String.valueOf(i);
    key++;
}

np.setDisplayedValues(values);
```

and when i click on picker on value:
-1 then display -19 on place -1
on -2 is -20
on -3 is ok.

why ?

---

First click on value: [bad display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3yMh.png)
Second click on value: [good display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXIQr.png)

I don't have any handler on it.

---

Solved:

```
values[key] = String.valueOf(i) + " ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading your `NumberPicker`s values but these are inconsistent with your `displayValues`. You need to map the "real" values [0-70] back to your `displayValues` [-20-50].

Comment: No, that's not it. This only occurs when dealing with _negative_ numbers. Adding a space solves it.